# How to prove A ∪ B = B if A ⊆ B?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

My question is regarding how to prove that A∪B = B if A ⊆ B. I can understand it logically (i.e. since A ⊆ B then if x ∈ A ⇒ x ∈ B hence A∪B = B and thus A∪B = B ⟺ B = B.

However, I know this is not the correct way of proving that it is true. From my understanding, to prove two things are equal in set theory (for example, A = B) one would prove that A ⊆ B AND B ⊆ A. I have no real idea regarding how to go about doing this using my example. I've tried a couple of different approaches but I'm fairly quickly left not knowing how to proceed.

Here is my current attempt:

1. If x ∈ A ⇒ x ∈ B
2. A∪B = x ∈ A OR x ∈ B
3. If x ∈ B ⇒ A∪B ⊆ B
4. If x ∈ A ⇒ x ∈ B ⇒ A∪B ⊆ B
5. Hence A∪B ⊆ B has been shown.

but this goes only one way and I'm unsure if it actually proves anything or not.

Comment: If $x\in B$, then $x\in A\cup B$. This shows $B\subseteq A\cup B$.

Comment: Don't use $=$ in sentences like "$A\cup B$ $=$ $x\in A$ OR $x\in B.$" You can say "$x\in A\cup B$ $\iff$ $x\in A$ OR $x\in B.$"

Comment: Step 3 and 4 don't quite work. The goal is to prove that $x\in A\cup B$ implies $x\in B$. The conclusion that $A\cup B\subset B$ is not implied by $x\in B$ for some particular $x\in A\cup B$. Step 3 should be $x\in B \implies x\in B$ and step 4 $x\in A \implies x\in B$. From those two, step 2 implies that $x\in A\cup B \implies x\in B$, whence $A\cup B \subset B$.